# Pandas slicing FutureWarning with 0.21.0

Tags: python, pandas, filter, slice

I'm trying to select a subset of a subset of a dataframe, selecting only some columns, and filtering on the rows.

```
df.loc[df.a.isin(['Apple', 'Pear', 'Mango']), ['a', 'b', 'f', 'g']]
```

However, I'm getting the error:

```
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.
```

What 's the correct way to slice and filter now?

Comment: That is not an error, that is a *warning*. But what it's telling you is that one of your labels, likely your column labels, isn't contained in the data-frame. The current behavior will be to fail silently and return a column with `NaN`s. In the future, it will raise an error instead.

Comment: Thank you, I misunderstood what was meant by index - and how re-indexing was relevant.  Yes I just made a typo in one of my labels.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that the bit about `.reindex()` is confusing. EDIT although it makes sense when you read [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-with-list-with-missing-labels-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

#### TL;DR: There is likely a typo or spelling error in the column header names.

This is a change introduced in `v0.21.1`, and has been explained in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#indexing-with-a-list-with-missing-labels-is-deprecated) at length -

> Previously, selecting with a list of labels, where one or more labels
> were missing would always succeed, returning `NaN` for missing labels.
> This will now show a `FutureWarning`. In the future this will raise a
> `KeyError` ([GH15747](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15747)). This warning will trigger on a `DataFrame` or a
> `Series` for using `.loc[]` or `[[]]` when passing a list-of-labels with at
> least 1 missing label.

For example,

```
df

     A    B  C
0  7.0  NaN  8
1  3.0  3.0  5
2  8.0  1.0  7
3  NaN  0.0  3
4  8.0  2.0  7
```

Try some kind of slicing as you're doing -

```
df.loc[df.A.gt(6), ['A', 'C']]

     A  C
0  7.0  8
2  8.0  7
4  8.0  7
```

No problem. Now, try replacing `C` with a non-existent column label -

```
df.loc[df.A.gt(6), ['A', 'D']]
FutureWarning: Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.
     
     A   D
0  7.0 NaN
2  8.0 NaN
4  8.0 NaN
```

So, in your case, the error is because of the column labels you pass to `loc`. Take another look at them.

Comment: What if I *want* a `KeyError` to be raised if there are any missing labels? That is, if I actually *want* the new behavior? Right now `.loc[list_of_names]` will give this warning, which I do not want to see. Any way to disable it?

Comment: @OrenBen-Kiki Simplest way is to update to the latest version, it throws a KeyError in the latest versions.

Comment: Yes, but it also gives the warning... Currently my choices are to use `reindex` (and lose the safety that `loc` gives me), or use `loc` and get a ton of warnings. Is there a third option (get the safety and *not* get the warnings)?

Comment: @OrenBen-Kiki Like I said, in more recent versions (from at least 0.25, possibly earlier versions), it throws a KeyError straight away. Now I'm not sure what you mean by "warnings", are you referring to the traceback?

Comment: Ah, got it, the warning is only generated if there is an actual missing key.  Which is the only behavior which makes sense ;-) It would have been so nice if `KeyError` actually specified what the value of the key was...

Comment: @OrenBen-Kiki it does... At the bottom of the traceback message, in IPython at least. Don't think you can save or print it when catching an error, it's just a readable traceback dump.

Comment: @OrenBen-Kiki, @cs95 - When using JupyterLab, I needed to use `warnings.simplefilter('error', FutureWarning)` in order to get a Traceback and actually see what piece of my code caused the FutureWarning.  [Reference](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26329#issuecomment-491130713)

Answer (score 3):

This error also occurs with `.append` call when the list contains new columns. To avoid this

Use:

```
df=df.append(pd.Series({'A':i,'M':j}), ignore_index=True)
```

Instead of,

```
df=df.append([{'A':i,'M':j}], ignore_index=True)
```

Full error message:

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1472:
>   FutureWarning: Passing list-likes to .loc or with any missing label
>   will raise KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an
>   alternative.

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50230080/207661

Comment: Similarly, if you need to append two dataframes you can use `df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([dict]), ignore_index=True)`

Comment: As the question title says, this is a warning, not an error

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain the index you can pass list comprehension instead of a column list:

```
loan_data_inputs_train.loc[:,[i for i in List_col_without_reference_cat]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I'm not sure that I correctly understood you, but seems that next way could be acceptable for you:

`df[df['a'].isin(['Apple', 'Pear', 'Mango'])][['a', 'b', 'f', 'g']]`

Snippet description:

```
df['a'].isin(['Apple', 'Pear', 'Mango']) # it's "filter" by data in each row in column *a*

df[['a', 'b', 'f', 'g']] # it's "column filter" that provide ability select specific columns set
```