# Pandas: FutureWarning: Passing list-likes to .loc or []

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I run my script, Pandas gives the following: 'Future warning'

```
FutureWarning:
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.
```

My script:

```
import io

data = io.StringIO('''A,B,M
AM,1,
AMC,2,
''')
df = pd.read_csv(data)

r=['CAR']
s=['CAR_M']

for i,j in zip(r,s):
    df=df.append([{'A':i,'M':j}], ignore_index=True)
```

The same warning appear if "ignore_index=False". I don't know how to reindex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems need `Series` constructor for correct append new row:

```
for i,j in zip(r,s):
    df=df.append(pd.Series({'A':i,'M':j}), ignore_index=True)

print (df)
     A    B      M
0   AM  1.0    NaN
1  AMC  2.0    NaN
2  CAR  NaN  CAR_M
```